# In Kafka v 1.x.x and later, In it possible to get Message Timestamp given that I have message offset and partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In Kafka v 1.x.x and later, Is it possible to get Message Timestamp given that I have message's topic offset and partition.
That is

> I/P : Topic Partition Offset
>
> Expected O/P : Message Create Timestamp of that exact message

One way of solving this approach is to use seek and assign and start consuming message. After consumption, get the consumer record timestamp.

However I wanted to know if there is any API in Java/Scala/Console which helps in achieveing this ?

Comment: offsetsForTimes(Map<TopicPartition, Long> timestampsToSearch) will return the offset number for that timestamp moment, for the partitions you request

Comment: @aran The offset is already known. That method is if you only have a timestamp

Comment: @cricket_007 Exactly. I Know the offset. I need the message create Time / Message Produce Time.

Comment: @cricket_007 misunderstood completely the question, sorry folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`consumer.assign` to set the partition, and `consumer.seek` to set the offset, are the API methods you want, yes. After those, poll like normal, then get the timestamp

Or you can show timestamps in the CLI like so

```
kafka-console-consumer ... --max-messages=1 --property print.timestamp=true \
   --topic "${TOPIC}" --partition $PARTITION --offset $OFFSET
```

`kafkacat` can also be used to reduce the verbosity of that all with the `-f '%T'` format

This is all available in Kafka 0.10.2 and later, when message timestamps were added

Comment: Is this possible via Java Client API ?

Comment: The CLI tools are just wrappers around Scala code, which import the Java API, so yes... As mentioned, Consumer.seek is what you need